# I tried Commiting and pushing changes made to my application to Git but i'm getting the .vs/ db lock error

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019

The actual error message is :

```
Git failed with a fatal error. error: open(".vs/Server/sqlite3/db.lock"): Permission denied fatal: Unable to process path .vs/Server/sqlite3/db.lock
```

In the past when I get this message I go to repository settings and click on `Add .gitignore` option then retry pushing. But this time around the `Add .gitignore` option is absent. On the `.gitignore` file, `.vs/` statement is there but dblock error keeps popping up

Answer (score 0):

so apparently it was git was cached. I ran the script below to remove the cache and was able to commit and push changes afterwards:

git rm --cached -r .vs/*